# Haskell exe. file and cmd

Tags: haskell, exe

I'm new to Haskell world, I compiles a simple exe.program

```
main = do  
    putStrLn "Hello, what's your name?"  
    name <- getLine  
    putStrLn ("Hi " ++ name)
```

How can I keep the cmd open, like Console.ReadLine() in other languages.
Thanks for help.

Comment: Generally though, it shouldn't be necessary to have the program keep the console open. You should just keep a persistant console window where you can see the results even after the program has completely terminated. Just run the program in that window again each time you need it. — Of course, consoles are always a pain when working on Windows; apparently that's your OS? Consider switching to a GNU/Linux or installing Cygwin...

Comment: Of course you r right, the idea it s just to see the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just read a line again

```
main = do  
    putStrLn "Hello, what's your name?"  
    name <- getLine  
    putStrLn ("Hi " ++ name) 
    getLine
```